# Cakephp : getting error while using Router::connect

Tags: php, cakephp

For example this is my domain- http://myproject.com/ and i have used

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'public', 'action' => 'index'));
```

in `routes.php` to get my project home page at main URL http://myproject.com/ it's working and I want as it is, but in my project's other links are not working. Suppose i click on a link brand it will generate a link like this -http://myproject.com/public/displayproduct where original working link is http://myproject.com/index.php/public/displayproduct so it is showing error because of skipping index.php. What should i do to skip index.php and get running all my links?

Comment: Its seems .htaccess  problem. Can you share your root .htaccess for cakephp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems its happening due to your .htaccess.Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled and `.htaccess` should placed like below in Cakephp 2.x:

Cakephp root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and webroot `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [installation guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#i-can-t-use-url-rewriting):

> If you don’t want or can’t get mod_rewrite (or some other compatible module) up and running on your server,
>   you’ll need to use CakePHP’s built in pretty URLs. In config/app.php,
>   uncomment the line that looks like:
>
> ```
> 'App' => [
>     // ...
>     // 'baseUrl' => env('SCRIPT_NAME'),
> ]
> ```
>
> Also remove these .htaccess files:
>
> ```
> /.htaccess
> webroot/.htaccess
> ```
>
> This will make your URLs look like
>   `www.example.com/index.php/controllername/actionname/param` rather than
>   `www.example.com/controllername/actionname/param`.

Comment: I don't know what you've done, or what you have read in your php error log.